# Apply on MATLAB a constant function on a array returning then an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, function

I apply a function (which is a **constant**) to an array, I thought that it will return an array in which the values were all equal to one but it returns just 1.

```
q=@(x) 1
q([1:n].*10)

ans = 1
```

I thought that it will return : ans = [ 1,1,1,1,1,...]

Comment: If you want it to return an array, make it return an array. `1` is not an array. It doesn't "apply a function on an array", it's just a function that happens to be given an array as input. You might be confusing it with `arrayfun` (which is unneeded here).

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Do you want to make each element of `x` be 1? Why are you trying to define a function for that? It seems to me that you're translating from a different language, and missing basic concepts of the MATLAB language. If this is the case, I recommend you look through [the excellent "MATLAB basics" tutorials that The MathWorks has put out](https://www.mathworks.com/support/learn-with-matlab-tutorials.html).

Comment: @CrisLuengo it's a bit strange to define a function like this but I'm coding a  method of finite differences in order to solve -y''(x)+p(x)y'(x)+q(x)y(x) = f(x), with in a particular case p(x) =0 and q(x) =1. In my entire function, I apply the function q(x) to an array but when I take q=constante it return a constant and not an array (I want the array one row of ones).  Moreover, paradoxically, if f(x)= x+1 and I apply f to an array it returns an array...

Comment: That is not paradoxical. Type `1` in the MATLAB terminal. It will show you `1`. Type `x+1`, it will show you an array of equal size as `x`, with each element incremented by 1. This is how MATLAB works. Make your function the way [VolkanOzcan showed below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53125057/7328782).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

q needs a way to understand the output size.

```
q=@(x) zeros(size(x))+1;
q(1:10)
```

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted, I think it does what OP wants. But `zeros(...)+1` is the same as `ones(...)`.

Comment: I thought he might want to do other stuff than ones.

Comment: Yes, that is probably true.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your function is a constant but you have no 'x' in your inputs, so it returns the constant value for any input. Try:

`q=@(x) x.*0+1`

In this form your function will just mirror the input in whatever form it is (vector, matrix or constant), this should give the result that you wanted :)

Comment: This does not return `1`, it returns `x`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Oops, you're right, that's what i get for not checking, thanks.